# How to avoid synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

I am building a Chrome Extension for our QA team.  On startup, the extension loads a config file and uses it to set properties on a global object.  Here is the code:

```
var qaExt = (function () {

    'use strict';

    // Properties fetched from config file
    var userHash, gitHash;

    function getBuildInfo() {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var buildInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                teamId = buildInfo.teamId;
                gitHash = buildInfo.gitHash;
            }
        };

        var path = ((vAPI.firefox) ? '/content' : '') + '/js/build_info.json';

        xhr.open("GET", path, false);
        xhr.send();
    }

    return {

        isDev: true,
        userSettings: {
            collapseAllowed: true,
            menuEnabled: true,
            experimental: false
        },
        teamId: teamId,
        gitHash: gitHash,
    };

})();
```

The code in the other files depends on the value of the properties 'teamId' and 'gitHash'.  This is why I load the config file synchronously here.  But I get the following warning in the console:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects on the end user's experience. For more help, 
check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

How can I do this without a synchronous AJAX request?  I do not want the other code to execute before these values are set.

Comment: i am not sure how chrome extensions work but aren't you able to create a promise and check if it resolves.

Comment: that ajax code is setup to be async... but you ultimately need to add a callback to getBuildInfo().

Comment: You could use `chrome.fileSystem`, but it's still async ?

Comment: @BobThomas - Are there promises in core javascript or does that require a library such as jQuery?

Comment: I normally use angular but i think you can create your own promise in vanilla quite easy probably a few google links away :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a callback function.

```
function getBuildInfo(callback) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var buildInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            teamId  = buildInfo.teamId;
            gitHash = buildInfo.gitHash;
            callback();
        }
    };

    var path = ((vAPI.firefox) ? '/content' : '') + '/js/build_info.json';

    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

getBuildInfo(function(){
 //ajax request success and done.

});
```

Here is the second option with return statement:

```
function getBuildInfo(callback) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var buildInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            callback(buildInfo.teamId, buildInfo.gitHash);
        }
    };

    var path = ((vAPI.firefox) ? '/content' : '') + '/js/build_info.json';

    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

getBuildInfo(function(teamId, gitHash){
 //ajax request success and done.

});
```

Comment: Should the return statement be inside of the callback?

Comment: @OnToTheNextOne that is entirely up to you. You know that when the callback is called whether you return the statement or set it globally that they are set.

Comment: That doesn't work because the application cannot continue until the values of the properties 'teamId' and 'gitHash' are set.  I just need the application to stop until the config file is loaded.  That's why I made it synchronous to begin with.

Comment: @OnToTheNextOne just put all your code in the callback. Or call the functions within the callback that need to be run after teamId and gitHash are set. Putting the code in the callback solves your problem with "application to stop until..", the application will stop till the callback is called.

Comment: @OnToTheNextOne: If you're wondering what code would look like if you put the entire application in a callback just look at jQuery where people put entire applications inside `ready()`